# Use curl in a loop to send data to the clients from the numbers fetched from database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, curl, sms-gateway

```
$text="text.";
//fetch from DB
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employee`");
while($query=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo $employee_mobile=$query['employee_mobile'];
  echo $url="http://mobile.ssexpertcompu.com/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&msisdn=".$employee_salary."&sid=78NSL&msg=".$text."&fl=0&gwid=2";

    $url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url); // to properly format the url 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

First employee record are fetched from DB,then using curl I'm sending message to their respective mobile numbers.The code for sending messages works fine without loop. I've seen some post how to use curl in a loop, but couldn't modify to my needs.

Comment: You appear to have put your real username and password in the edit history of this code - you are advised to change these credentials on the remote side now.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hi I've not added added any real username or passwords in my sms gateway link,could you please help me with the answer

Comment: OK. With regards to your question, there doesn't seem to be any lookup of each employee's mobile number. That would probably be something you need to add to the query string. Do you have documentation (online) for this SMS service?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not defined `$employee_salary` and should exchange it with `$employee_mobile`:

```
echo $employee_mobile = $query['employee_mobile'];
echo $url = "http://mobile.ssexpertcompu.com/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&msisdn=" . $employee_mobile . "&sid=78NSL&msg=" . $text . "&fl=0&gwid=2";
```